# How not to hard code the path of the DocumentationFile path in Visual Studio 2019 .csproj

Tags: visual-studio, path, environment-variables, visual-studio-2019

How to set the `DocumentationFile` dynamically to reference the current user's home drive? Is there a `$` variable to set? I checked in my project to TFS.  When another member of my team clones the source code to his workstation, the following node in the `.csproj` still references to the folder on my hard drive, and fails the compilation. So far we have to manually edit the `.csproj` file. Thanks.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>C:\Users\myName\source\repos\orgName\solutionName\projectName\.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-160) of common macros in Visual Studio.

The one you probably want is `$(ProjectDir)`

You can also use environment variables stored in the registry.  See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2019).

Examples:

`<FinalOutput>$(BIN_PATH)\MyAssembly.dll</FinalOutput>`

```
<Project DefaultTargets="FakeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <FinalOutput>$(BIN_PATH)\myassembly.dll</FinalOutput>
        <ToolsPath Condition=" '$(ToolsPath)' == '' ">
            C:\Tools
        </ToolsPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="FakeBuild">
        <Message Text="Building $(FinalOutput) using the tools at $(ToolsPath)..."/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply.  It leads me to find the $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) variable.  Here is the PropertyGroup

```html
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```